# Neo4j Spring Bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, neo4j

I have to following bean configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">



  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </beans:bean>

  <annotation-driven />
  <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


  <beans:bean id="graphDbFactory" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory"/>
  <beans:bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbFactory" factory-method="newEmbeddedDatabase">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="D:/opt/neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01/data/graph.db"/>
  </beans:bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="net.spring.neo4j" />
</beans:beans>
```

However I am getting lock error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:580)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:339)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@2d9d7019' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:316)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db\store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't lock lock file D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db\lock because another process already holds the lock.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getLockFileBasedFileLock(FileLock.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
    ... 44 more

Mar 23, 2014 12:19:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:580)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:339)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@2d9d7019' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:316)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db\store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't lock lock file D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db\lock because another process already holds the lock.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getLockFileBasedFileLock(FileLock.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
    ... 44 more

Mar 23, 2014 12:19:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /Spring-Neo4j threw load() exception
java.io.IOException: Couldn't lock lock file D:\opt\neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01\data\graph.db\lock because another process already holds the lock.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getLockFileBasedFileLock(FileLock.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:316)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to manually remove the lock and it still does not work.

Edit:
tried with spring-data I am still having the same problem

Comment: Do you have shutdown hook in place in your application - this helps releasing the lock cleanly when your application is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

What does the rest of your config look like?

Do you by chance open the graph database with the same path for another bean or config ?

It usually only happens if two instances are trying to access the same db.

You could also use the factory bean
 `org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean`.

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="target/config-test"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```